# Grabar y guardar video con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, laravel

Hola estoy trabajando en un proyecto en laravel 5.6, quiero activar la camara del dispositivo y grabar un video de pocos segundos, y guardarlo en el servidor, por ahora tengo esto que activa la camara, no se que mas hacer para grabar y guardar en el servidor, aqui el codigo que llevo en el momento:

```
<script>
    navigator.getUserMedia =
            navigator.getUserMedia ||
            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
            navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
            navigator.msGetUserMedia;
            window.URL = window.URL || 
            window.webkitURL || 
            window.mozURL || 
            window.msURL;

    var video = document.querySelector('video');

    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {    
        navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true},
        function(stream){
            var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            console.log(video.src);
        },
        function () {
            document.writeLn("problema");
        });
    }else{
        document.writeLn("video capture no soporta");
    }
    $("#stop").click(function() {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
    });
</script>
```

Gracias.